# How to assign Mann-Whitney variables and calculate p value on Rstudio?

Tags: r

I'm having trouble coding my variables (food.type and inter.distance) before doing my wilcox.test. Complete novice, can anyone help?

```
food.type   inter.distance
leaves           25
fruit            15
none             25
none              25
fruit   10
none    15
none    10
none    10
bark    5
fruit   15
fruit   10
none    20
leaves  25
none    25
none    15
bark    25
fruit   15
leaves  15
fruit   25
none    20
fruit   25
fruit   15
none    5
none    5
none    5
none    5
none    10
none    10
none    25
none    20
leaves  5
none    10
none    10
fruit   20
bark    20
none    15
leaves  5
none    5
leaves  20
fruit   15
leaves  25
bark    10
none    20
none    10
```

--

```
GROUP<-factor(GROUP,c(1,2,3,4),labels=c('leaves','fruit','bark','none'))
#Error in factor(GROUP, c(1, 2, 3, 4), labels = c("leaves", "fruit", "bark",  : 
# object 'GROUP' not found
```

Comment: Is `GROUP` in a `data.frame`? If so you'll need to reference the `data.frame` is in. You'll probably want something like `df$GROUP = factor(df$GROUP,c(1,2,3,4),labels=c('leaves','fruit','bark','none'))` where `df` is the name of the `data.frame`.

Comment: Hi, yes in a data.frame. Just tried that, came out with this error?
> factor(df$GROUP,c(1,2,3,4),labels=c('leaves','fruit','bark','none'))
Error in df$GROUP : object of type 'closure' is not subsettable

Comment: Ope sorry, that was my mistake. `food.type` is the name of the variable in the `data.frame`. Maybe start with this `df$GROUP = factor(df$food.type)` and then see play with the levels and labels if you want it ordered or labeled differently.